# Want to know how to match up to a certain string - tcl regexp

Tags: match, tcl

```
How do I pattern match this in TCL?

set game1 base_ball_ABC_10_100_a_b_c
set game2 base_ball_CDE_20_200_d_e_f
set game3 base_bat_DEF_40_400_j_k_l
```

The regexp arg below does not seem to work since it will match up to 1st digit (ie: _10, _20)?

```
if { ![regexp {^([^0-9]+)(.*)$} $k3 - bb digit] } {
```

I wonder what would be the regexp to match `base_ball`, and `AB_10_100_a_b_c`? The above regexp seems to match up to a `DIGIT`?

I would like it to match `[base_ball or base_bat]` and then match `[ABC_10_100, CDE_20_200]`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `regexp` if the strings have an equal number of underscores, and if all your need is always before and after the 2nd underscore:

```
set k3 {base_ball_ABC_10_100_a_b_c}
set parts [split $k3 "_"]
set part1 [join [lrange $parts 0 1] "_"]
# base_ball
set part2 [join [lrange $parts 2 end] "_"]
# ABC_10_100_a_b_c
```

Taking your previous question in consideration as well, you may not need to join either, if you're only counting the unique values, so doing

```
set k3 {base_ball_ABC_10_100_a_b_c}
set parts [split $k3 "_"]
set part1 [lrange $parts 0 1]
set part2 [lrange $parts 2 end]
```

should probably be enough.

Docs for [split](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [lrange](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm), [join](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm)

---

If you still want to use regexp, then I'd advise reading [re_syntax](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), and the expression really depends on a lot of things. There can be a lot of different expressions that work with your data, but the best expression can only be crafted by knowing about the data, and edge cases. From what I can assume, I'd guess something like this may work:

```
regexp {^([^_]+_[^_]+)_(.+)$} $k3 - bb digit
```

Where `[^_]+` means that any character will be matched, except for `_`s, so that the above matches:

- `^` - beginning of string
- `[^_]+` - any non `_`s
- `_` - one `_`
- `[^_]+` any non `_`s
- `_` one `_`
- `.+` - any characters
- `$` - end of string